# Compile with 3 different preambles

Tags: compiling, preamble

I have a tex file without a preamble (it starts with \begin{document}) to which I need to add a preamble that depends on the output type. I cannot use conditionals here because the first line (\documentclass) is also different in the preambles. I thought of using a bash script to combine the tex file and a preamble based on the output type and then send it to compile.

The preambles do have conditionals that are used within the tex file.

Is my analysis correct, or can this be done directly in LaTeX?

**Improvements in the way of asking**

```
preambulo-pdf.txt (content)
    
\documentclass{book}

... continues with loading packages with options

preambulo-epub.txt (content)

\documentclass[oneside,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}

... continues with loading packages, which are much fewer than in preambulo-pdf.txt

preambulo-art.txt (content)

\documentclass{article}

... continues with loading packages, which are much fewer than in preambulo-pdf.txt and preambulo-art.txt
```

And then I have a file named .tex, which I send for compilation. If the output is to PDF (from TeXstudio), the command is:

```
latexmk -f --shell-escape --interaction=nonstopmode -pdflatex=lualatex -output-format=pdf -synctex=1
```

If the output is to ePub, the command for compilation is:

```
tex4ebook -e build.lua <nombre-del-archivo>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could do `\ifmybool\documentclass{article}\fi`.  Regardless, you can look into `\input{preamble-a}`.  But you're a little vague on what you're actually wanting to do, so it's hard to give an answer.

Comment: Thank you, Teepeemm. I will look into studying the option you suggested. I have added some further details to my question to clarify any doubts.

Comment: You can definitely move `\documentclass` into the preamble.  I'm not sure if there's a way that TeX can tell if it's tex4ebook or lualatex from within the TeX file.  Are both `preambulo-pdf` and `preambulo-art` for pdf output?

Comment: No, "preambulo-pdf" is only for the PDF, and "preambulo-art" is the same for both PDF and EPUB.

Comment: your question is not very clear you can have conditionals before `\documentclass` or more simply have three separate top level files each `\input` the same body

Comment: Thank you, David. That's the answer to what I initially asked: I can have conditionals before the \documentclass, great.